# Unicity of solution for a parabolic problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, regularity-theory-of-pdes

How can I show that the parabolic problem

> $$ \begin{cases}
> \partial_xu- \Delta u=0 & \mathbb{R} \times (0,+ \infty)\\ 
> u(x,0)=f(x) & \mathbb{R} 
> \end{cases} $$

has a unique solution? Can I use the maximum principle for the Laplace Equation?

Comment: You'll need some assumptions for $f$, otherwise it's false. There are counterexamples due to Tychonoff, http://www.mathnet.ru/links/1fc4d116bc6753c2908d185847491b01/sm6410.pdf .

Comment: You can also look in Chapter 7.1 of the book "Partial Differential Equations" by Fritz John for details on the Tychonoff result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [uniqueness heat equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215524/uniqueness-heat-equation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classical result of uniqueness requires only that
$$
                \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx < \infty \mbox{ (finite heat/energy) } \\
                  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|u(x,t)|dx \le M < \infty,\;\;\; t > 0.
$$