# Show that solutions to heat equation conserve mass

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How does one solve the following problem:

> Let $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)|dx < \infty$ and let $u(x,t)$ be a solution to the following Cauchy problem:
>   $$\left\{
>                 \begin{array}{ll}
>                   u_t - u_{xx} = 0\qquad \text{for }x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t > 0\\
>                   u(x,0) = f(x) \qquad \text{for }x \in \mathbb{R}^n
>               \end{array}
>               \right.$$
>   Show that 
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u(x,t) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)dx$$
>   for all $t > 0$.

I can see how it could be done if I could show that $\lim_\limits{x \to \pm \infty} u_{xx}(x,t) = 0$, but I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that. Is there another way (without using Fourier transforms)?

Comment: This is not true without some restriction on $u$: there is a classic example due to Tychonoff with $u(x,0) = 0$ but $u(\cdot,t)$ unbounded for all $t>0$. Intuitively speaking, without some decay condition on $u$ you can "add mass at infinity".

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thank you. It wasn't stated, but I think it was meant to be implied that the solution $u$ must be $C^2_1 ( \mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty) )$.  In this case, is the condition on $f$ unnecessary then?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis:  can you provide a link or other reference (preferably online) to Tychonoff's example?

Comment: @mlaci:  what is $C_1^2(\Bbb R \times (0, \infty))$?

Comment: @RobertLewis I apologize, I thought this was standard notation. From Evans' "Partial Differential Equations", 2nd ed., p. 702: $C^2_1(U_T)  = \{ u: U_T \to \mathbb{R} | u, D_xu, D^2_xu, u_t \in C(U_T) \}$

Comment: @mlaci:  thanks, I'm not too familiar with Evan's book, though I should be!

Comment: @mlaci:  is $U_T = \Bbb R \times (0, T)$?

Comment: @RobertLewis I think that's just an arbitrary domain in that case, but in section 2.3 it means $U \times (0,T]$, where $U$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and he calls this $U_T$ then the parabolic interior of $\bar{U}_T = U \times [0,T]$ (page 52). Althought I'll note that he uses the notation $C^2_1(\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty))$ on page 50.

Comment: @mlaci: no, the counterexample is smooth. There's a fairly readable description of it on page 6 of [these notes](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/yan/847ch3.pdf). To rule this kind of thing out you need to impose bounds, not just regularity - to get uniqueness we normally assume a growth bound something like $|u(x,t)| \le C e^{|x|^2}$. Once you have uniqueness, I think the integral representation formula for the solution in terms of $f$ is one way to prove the conservation of mass.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thank you very much! I'm still a little confused about some details, but it's way late here and I really need to get some sleep. I'll come back to this question tomorrow.

Comment: @RobertLewis This question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339240/unicity-of-solution-for-a-parabolic-problem talks about the Tychonoff example. As one of the comments says, it's on page 211 of Fritz John's book.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis:  too bad my Russian is so weak . . .

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Sorry, I'm still really lost. Having the integral representation $\int_{\mathbb{R^n}} \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{(1/2)}} e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t}} f(y) dy$, how do I show that the integral is the same for all fixed $t > 0$?

Comment: @RobertLewis https://math.temple.edu/~gutierre/math8141/heat.equation.notes.pdf page 10

Comment: Fubini gives $\int \int K(|x-y|,t) f(y) dy dx = \int \int K(|x-y|,t) dx f(y) dy$, so since the heat kernel has unit mass at each $t>0$ you're done, no?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Ohhhh. Yes! I'm an idiot. I was thinking it was supposed to be done with something like this: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-086-mathematical-methods-for-engineers-ii-spring-2006/readings/am54.pdf (top of page 2). Thank you very much!

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Would you like to post that as answer so I can mark it as accepted?